# Showing and hiding panels on button click c#

Tags: c#, winforms, button, show-hide, panels

I have 4 panels (on top of each others). i want to hide all panels and show one of them depending on the clicked button. when i launch the application and click on the button, it successfully hides all panels but it doesn't show the panel that i want. what am i doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
namespace Detailing
{
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public void hidePanels()
    {
        welcomePanel.Width = 0;
        homePanel.Width = 0;
        historyPanel.Width = 0;
        savePanel.Width = 0;
    }
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Load += new EventHandler(MainForm_Load);
    }
    private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        hidePanels();
        welcomePanel.Width = 1306;
    }

    private void homeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        hidePanels();
        homePanel.Width = 1306;
    }
}
}
```

**P.S.** i tried to use `welcomePanel.Hide();` and `homePanel.Show();` and it didn't work. Also i tried to use `welcomePanel.Visible = false;` and `homePanel.Visible = true;` but sadly it didn't work as well.

Comment: You should be sure to not have included a panel inside another panel. In other words, no panel should be a child of another panel, otherwise hiding the parent also hides the childs.

Comment: Based on the names, seems to me these really should be different forms instead of nested panels.

Comment: Don't mess with the width but simply make the invisible: `yadayada.Visible=true/false:` Also: Put them in a List<Panel> so you can loop over them! Of course it will work. But, yes they must not be nested. To avoid that move them on top of them either in code or with the keyboard(!!!!) but not with the mouse(!!!!!!!)

Comment: Check your panels hierarchy in `Document Outline` window in Visual Studio

Comment: @TaW Thank you for the suggestions and your notes. I did try the Visible = true/false first but it didn't work. The problem was that the panels were nested. Now it works just fine. Thank you.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange The idea is I'm trying to make an application with the new Windows 10 look. That's why I was avoiding creating new forms. The problem is that the panels were nested, that's why when I hide the parent, the child will be hidden as well. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Panel is a control container. This means that, if (using the designer) you have dragged a panel over the surface of another panel, it becomes a child of the underlying panel. You can see easily this fact when you try to move the underlying panel. All the childs move together.

You can draw your panel in different position of the form and keep just one as a placeholder for all the other panels. When you load the form or in the form constructor you can move by code the other panels in the same Location of the reference panel.

So,assuming welcomePanel is the reference panel you can write:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public void hidePanels()
    {
        welcomePanel.Visible = false;
        homePanel.Visible = false;
        historyPanel.Visible = false;
        savePanel.Visible = false;
    }
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Load += new EventHandler(MainForm_Load);
        homePanel.Location = welcomePanel.Location;
        historyPanel.Location = welcomePanel.Location;
        savePanel.Location = welcomePanel.Location;        
    }
    private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        hidePanels();
        welcomePanel.Visible = true;
    }

    private void homeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        hidePanels();
        homePanel.Visible = true;
    }
    ..... and so on ...

}
```

Another approach is to use a TabControl and show/hides the TabPage as you require

Comment: Your method worked. I guess the problem was that I added the second panel inside the first one. Thank you very much for your detailed answer, it was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

To make your code short just directly set your panel to false on their properties
so and set to true only the welcomePanel. [this the property of the panel just find the Visible then set it to false or true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7s0zp.png)

namespace Detailing
{
public partial class MainForm : Form
{

```
public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Load += new EventHandler(MainForm_Load);
}
private void homeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    homePanel.Visible = true;
}
```

//and so on......

}
}