# How to you make a button that hides multiple other elements in visual studio on a windows forms app?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I Don't know how to code, but I wanna make a button that hides multiple elements, and a button that shows those elements again.

Comment: Does this help you ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43942649/showing-and-hiding-panels-on-button-click-c-sharp

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If an answer solves your problem mark it as an acceptable answer. If it helps you give it an upvote. If the answer is off-topic or doesn’t help at all, downvote or add a comment. See also [stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)

Comment: I have made an answer. If you don't mind, you could click '✔' to mark my reply as the accepted answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

## `Visible property`

You just need to modify the `Visible property` of the control to achieve the effect you want.

### Form

[image]

### code:

```
private void button2_Click (object sender, EventArgs e) {
    checkBox1.Visible = false;
    label1.Visible = false;
    listBox1.Visible = false;
    button3.Visible = false;
    }

private void button1_Click (object sender, EventArgs e) {
    checkBox1.Visible = true;
    label1.Visible = true;
    listBox1.Visible = true;
    button3.Visible = true;
    }
```

### Demo:

[image]

#### If you have questions about my answer, please comment below.

Comment: Does it help you?

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any others questions.